# Camel File Consumer errors with no feedback

Tags: apache-camel

I am running an application that uses Apache Camel for file processing. The application works perfectly on my Windows, and on a CentOS for testing.

However, when running on a RHEL I get a strange behavior that shows not much info. Here's an extract of the log:

```
Configured property: initialDelay on bean: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultScheduledPollConsumerScheduler@ad834fbd with value: 1000
2019-02-28 16:09:46,037 main                                                     TRACE org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport                   Configured property: delay on bean: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultScheduledPollConsumerScheduler@ad834fbd with value: 500
2019-02-28 16:09:46,037 main                                                     TRACE org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport                   Configured property: useFixedDelay on bean: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultScheduledPollConsumerScheduler@ad834fbd with value: true
2019-02-28 16:09:46,037 main                                                     TRACE org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport                   Configured property: scheduledExecutorService on bean: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultScheduledPollConsumerScheduler@ad834fbd with value: 
2019-02-28 16:09:46,037 main                                                     TRACE org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport                   Configured property: timeUnit on bean: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultScheduledPollConsumerScheduler@ad834fbd with value: MILLISECONDS
2019-02-28 16:09:46,037 main                                                     TRACE org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport                      Starting service
2019-02-28 16:09:46,037 main                                                     DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExecutorServiceManager          Created new ScheduledThreadPool for source: Consumer[file:///opt/IBM/WebSphere90/tmp/FILES/OUT/PROCESSED/BASEII_FRIDA_OUTGOING_PROC/CORPORATION_8/TO_PROCESS_STX?charset=UTF-8&doneFileName=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D.stx&move=.done&moveFailed=.error&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=1500] with name: file:///opt/IBM/WebSphere90/tmp/FILES/OUT/PROCESSED/BASEII_FRIDA_OUTGOING_PROC/CORPORATION_8/TO_PROCESS_STX?charset=UTF-8&doneFileName=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D.stx&move=.done&moveFailed=.error&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=1500 -> org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.SizedScheduledExecutorService@bac57329[file:///opt/IBM/WebSphere90/tmp/FILES/OUT/PROCESSED/BASEII_FRIDA_OUTGOING_PROC/CORPORATION_8/TO_PROCESS_STX?charset=UTF-8&doneFileName=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D.stx&move=.done&moveFailed=.error&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=1500]
2019-02-28 16:09:46,037 main                                                     DEBUG o.a.camel.impl.DefaultScheduledPollConsumerScheduler         Scheduling poll (fixed delay) with initialDelay: 1000, delay: 500 (milliseconds) for: file:///opt/IBM/WebSphere90/tmp/FILES/OUT/PROCESSED/BASEII_FRIDA_OUTGOING_PROC/CORPORATION_8/TO_PROCESS_STX?charset=UTF-8&doneFileName=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D.stx&move=.done&moveFailed=.error&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=1500
2019-02-28 16:09:46,037 main                                                     TRACE o.a.c.util.concurrent.SizedScheduledExecutorService          canScheduleOrExecute 0 < 1000 -> true
2019-02-28 16:09:46,038 main                                                     TRACE org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.CamelThreadFactory          Created thread[Camel (CamelContext) thread #58 - file:///opt/IBM/WebSphere90/tmp/FILES/OUT/PROCESSED/BASEII_FRIDA_OUTGOING_PROC/CORPORATION_8/TO_PROCESS_STX] -> Thread[Camel (CamelContext) thread #58 - file:///opt/IBM/WebSphere90/tmp/FILES/OUT/PROCESSED/BASEII_FRIDA_OUTGOING_PROC/CORPORATION_8/TO_PROCESS_STX,5,main]
2019-02-28 16:09:46,038 main                                                     INFO  org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext                   Route: FRIDABaseIIFileOutgoingTransport started and consuming from: file:///opt/IBM/WebSphere90/tmp/FILES/OUT/PROCESSED/BASEII_FRIDA_OUTGOING_PROC/CORPORATION_8/TO_PROCESS_STX?charset=UTF-8&doneFileName=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D.stx&move=.done&moveFailed=.error&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=1500
2019-02-28 16:09:46,038 main                                                     TRACE org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport                      Starting service
2019-02-28 16:09:46,038 main                                                     INFO  org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext                   Apache Camel 2.21.1 (CamelContext: CamelContext) is shutting down
2019-02-28 16:09:46,038 main                                                     TRACE org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper                          Stopping service org.a down service org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteController@36b5248f
2019-02-28 16:09:46,038 main                                                     TRACE org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport                      Servpache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteController@36b5248f
2019-02-28 16:09:46,038 main                                                     TRACE org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper                          Shuttingice already stopped
2019-02-28 16:09:46,039 main                                                     INFO  org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy                Starting to graceful shutdown 26 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
2019-02-28 16:09:46,039 main                                                     DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExecutorServiceManager          Created new ThreadPool for source: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy@1950c033 with name: ShutdownTask. -> org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.RejectableThreadPoolExecutor@33d3ff79[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0][ShutdownTask]
2019-02-28 16:09:46,040 main                                                     TRACE org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.CamelThreadFactory          Created thread[Camel (CamelContext) thread #59 - ShutdownTask] -> Thread[Camel (CamelContext) thread #59 - ShutdownTask,5,main]
2019-02-28 16:09:46,040 Camel (CamelContext) thread #59 - ShutdownTask           DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy                There are 26 routes to shutdown
2019-02-28 16:09:46,041 Camel (CamelContext) thread #59 - ShutdownTask           TRACE org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy                Shutting down route: FRIDABaseIIFileOutgoingTransport with options [Default,CompleteCurrentTaskOnly]
2019-02-28 16:09:46,041 Camel (CamelContext) thread #59 - ShutdownTask           TRACE org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy                Suspending: Consumer[file:///opt/IBM/WebSphere90/tmp/FILES/OUT/PROCESSED/BASEII_FRIDA_OUTGOING_PROC/CORPORATION_8/TO_PROCESS_STX?charset=UTF-8&doneFileName=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D.stx&move=.done&moveFailed=.error&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=1500]
2019-02-28 16:09:46,041 Camel (CamelContext) thread #59 - ShutdownTask           TRACE org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper                          Suspending service Consumer[file:///opt/IBM/WebSphere90/tmp/FILES/OUT/PROCESSED/BASEII_FRIDA_OUTGOING_PROC/CORPORATION_8/TO_PROCESS_STX?charset=UTF-8&doneFileName=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D.stx&move=.done&moveFailed=.error&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=1500]
2019-02-28 16:09:46,041 Camel (CamelContext) thread #59 - ShutdownTask           TRACE org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy                Suspend complete for: Consumer[file:///opt/IBM/WebSphere90/tmp/FILES/OUT/PROCESSED/BASEII_FRIDA_OUTGOING_PROC/CORPORATION_8/TO_PROCESS_STX?charset=UTF-8&doneFileName=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D.stx&move=.done&moveFailed=.error&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=1500]
2019-02-28 16:09:46,041 Camel (CamelContext) thread #59 - ShutdownTask           DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy                Route: FRIDABaseIIFileOutgoingTransport suspended and shutdown deferred, was consuming from: file:///opt/IBM/WebSphere90/tmp/FILES/OUT/PROCESSED/BASEII_FRIDA_OUTGOING_PROC/CORPORATION_8/TO_PROCESS_STX?charset=UTF-8&doneFileName=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D.stx&move=.done&moveFailed=.error&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=1500
2019-02-28 16:09:46,041 Camel (CamelContext) thread #59 - ShutdownTask           TRACE org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy                Shutting down route: FileErrorsReportToDB with options [Default,CompleteCurrentTaskOnly]
2019-02-28 16:09:46,041 Camel (CamelContext) thread #59 - ShutdownTask           DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy
```

Before the first line it's basically the same thing repeating the log for each file consumer route.

The context never stops... it's stays up and the file consumers keep logging this:

```
2019-02-28 16:09:46,996 Camel (CamelContext) thread #37 - file:///opt/IBM/WebSphere90/tmp/FILES/OUT/PROCESSED/LOGISTIC/CORPORATION_8/TO_PROCESS_STX/temp4 TRACE org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer                  Cannot start to poll: file:///opt/IBM/WebSphere90/tmp/FILES/OUT/PROCESSED/LOGISTIC/CORPORATION_8/TO_PROCESS_STX/temp4?charset=UTF-8&exclude=TEMP_.*&move=.done&moveFailed=.error&readLock=rename as its suspended
```

Can't find why the issue is. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade to a newer Camel version

Comment: Are you starting up Camel, and then some kind of error happens, and it shutdown itself right after? But you cannot see any errors or stacktraces in the log etc, and those fill consumers keep attempting to poll but they cannot because they are being shutdown. Maybe try to reduce your Camel app with fewer routes to see if you can pin-point this to a specific route, maybe a route that uses some special component that causes a problem on RHEL. Also you can try to attach a Java remote debugger and see if you can set a breakpoint at that "Stopping service" and see which services are the last

Comment: @ClausIbsen I was able to find the problem by commenting all routes and adding them one by one. Apparently the client put the same file paths for several routes and the error only showed up when starting 2 routes at the same time. Weird that with ALL of them the error didn't show up...

Comment: Yeah that is weird. So with 26 routes then you had 2 routes with a clash of file paths? That should not normally be an issue, however you will have multiple consumers race for the same files. Also its a bit weird that it works on other OSes but not on RHEL. All the file consumer does is create a java thread and use the java.io.File API to scan for files.

Comment: @ClausIbsen no, the other OS didn't have that issue. The client edited the properties file changing the directories (on that RHEL), causing them to clash. That was going to fail in any OS. However, what's weird is that it only showed the error when 2 routes where uncommented. Uncommenting all produce much more clashes but nothing is logged about those routes having the same consumer endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if your "main" is not staying up and running. So, when the app comes up, Camel initializes and configures the route. But, the "main" simply ends immediately. 
Would not explain why if would work on one OS and not another, but perhaps something else is different on those two environments?

Are you using Spring Boot?

See this: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, wasn't that tho. I manages to find the error, described in the comment to Claus.